# Quotient topologies of a closed interval from a closed interval

Tags: general-topology

Actually I have to ask for the quotient topologies in 3 different situations (which come from Ex. 5.5.7 of *Intro to Topology* by Min Yan).

Let's consider a function $f(x): [a, b] \to [\alpha = \underset{[a, b]}{\min} f, \beta = \underset{[a, b]}{\max} f]$.

1. Prove if $[a, b]$ has the usual topology, the quotient topology on $[\alpha, \beta]$ is the usual topology.

My attempt is:

$f$ is continuous from $[a, b]_{\text{usual}}$ to $[\alpha, \beta]_{\text{usual}}$. Then $[\alpha, \beta]_{\text{quotient}}$ is finer than $[\alpha, \beta]_{\text{usual}}$.

On the other hand, the identity map Id$(x) = x: [a, b]_{\text{usual}} \to [a, b]_{\text{usual}}$ is also continuous, so $f(x) = f \circ$ Id$(x): [a, b]_{\text{usual}} \to [\alpha, \beta]_{\text{quotient}}$ is also continuous. This implies the $[\alpha, \beta]_{\text{quotient}}$ is coarser than $[\alpha, \beta]_{\text{usual}}$. Therefore $[\alpha, \beta]_{\text{quotient}} = [\alpha, \beta]_{\text{usual}}$.

I want to ask if this is **correct & vigorous enough**.

2. Prove if $f$ is increasing, and $[a, b]$ has the lower limit topology, the quotient topology on $[\alpha, \beta]$ is the lower limit topology.

I'm stuck at showing that if $f(x) = \beta$, there is a $[c, d)$ being a subset of an open subset $U$ of $[\alpha, \beta]$. Is there any way to do so?
Or, is there another approach to prove the statement?

3. Find a general sufficient condition on $f$ s.t. if $[a, b]$ has the lower limit topology, the quotient topology on $[\alpha, \beta]$ is the usual topology.

The lower limit topology is finer than the usual one, right? But I have no idea what kind of conditions is needed. I only know if the function is already continuous in the case of usual $\to$ usual, [finer than usual] $\to$ usual is still continuous.

Many thanks again.

Comment: The fact that $f\colon [a, b]_\text{usual} \to [α, β]_\text{quotient}$ is continuous is trivial, and hence implies nothing. You still need to show that the quotient topology is coarser than the usual topology.

Comment: So may I know (if putting identity map doesn't work) how to do so? Many thanks.

Comment: You need to use that $[a, b]_\text{usual}$ is compact and $[α, β]_\text{usual}$ is Hausdorff.